# Why is my Bootcamp asking for a windows installer disk?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition, windows

Firstly my computer specs are:
MacBook Pro: (13-inch, Mid 2010)
Processor: 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory: 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

I'm trying to download windows 7 so I can play Overwatch, but my Bootcamp assistant keeps asking me to insert a "Windows installer disk" before the partition option comes up. Isn't the reason I use bootcamp so that I don't need a disk to run windows?

I have been trying to get my computer to run in windows 7 for the past 3 days now and nothing that various guides on the internet have suggested has worked. I know my computer is compatible with Windows, but it just won't boot my computer in Windows at all. I have been watching guides on Youtube, but since my model is 6 years old I'm assuming they don't work because they are using different models.

Can anyone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at, [Boot Camp Support](https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) and [How to install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468).

Comment: You can also just download the .iso file

Comment: @JMY1000 I have an ISO file, but it doesn't seem to work. Would buying a windows 7 copy replace the ISO file that doesn't work for me?

Comment: @BrianFuller That's strange, what exactly doesn't work? Also, what do you mean by "replace the ISO file that doesn't work for me?"?

Comment: @JMY1000 Well I'm currently trying to use an ISO file to start my computer in Windows, but the ISO file I'm using isn't letting me do that through BootCamp. If I download a non-physical new windows 7 file from Microsoft, will that allow me to start Windows in Bootcamp? I just want to know if I'm going to need a Physical hard copy disk version ordered from Amazon, or will a file downloaded from the Microsoft online store work?

Comment: @JMY1000 I guess what doesn't work is my ISO file? I think my Bootcamp is working, it's just whenever it finishes downloading and installing everything that it tells me I need it tells me to "Inset Windows 7 install disk", and I thought the ISO file for Windows 7 that I have would be a replacement for that, but it doesn't seem to be. Unless I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you still need to install a legal copy of windows so bootcamp can run windows. That is why the disk request. once windows is installed, bootcamp will run no problem.

Comment: Do I need a physical disk for this or can I find an online download?